# Correct way to take screenshot with Robotium and Cucumber

Tags: android, cucumber, robotium, android-testing

Which is the best way to take a **screenshot** when one scenario fails using **Robotium** and **Cucumber**?

I have tried (without success, because it doesn't execute ***runTest*** method) with this:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

@CucumberOptions(features = "features", tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class CustomInstrumentationTestCase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LaunchActivity> {

    protected Solo solo;

    public CustomInstrumentationTestCase() {
        super(LaunchActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        //...
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
        try {
            super.runTest();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            final String testCaseName = String.format("%s.%s", getClass().getName(), getName());
            solo.takeScreenshot(testCaseName);
            Log.w("Boom! Screenshot!", String.format("Captured screenshot for failed test: %s", testCaseName));

            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have set the permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Have you set the permission tag in the AndroidManifest.xml of the app under test?

Comment: Change the name of the test method to start with test. So in your case it could be testRun().

Comment: "So in your case it could be testRun()" nope - his code looks fine! the testRun methode is used because  assertion errors and report failures are thrown there.

Comment: try to add: @Before
  public void before() {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
  }

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

It will take a screenshot automatically when a tests fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your testclass seems fine. The runTest() methode is used to catch errors and failures and as a result make a screenshot.

To your class simply add a test like this:

```
public void testFailsForScreenShot(){
    fail();
}
```

Than run the test and you will find a screenshot.

Greetings

EDIT: Test for Screenshot:

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class TestScreenshot extends     ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LauncherActivity> {

private Solo solo;

public TestScreenshot(){
    super(LauncherActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

//Test if "Test" fails and takes Screenshot
public void testFailForScreenshot(){
    fail();
}


@Override
public void runTest() throws Throwable {
    try {
        super.runTest();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        String testCaseName = String.format("%s.%s", getClass().getName(), getName());
        solo.takeScreenshot(testCaseName);
        Log.w("Screenshot taken.", String.format("Captured screenshot for failed test: %s", testCaseName));

        throw t;
    }
}
```

Comment: just run the simple test above and check if there is any problem with your setup :)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, it doesn't go through neither setUp nor testFailForScreenshot nor, as I said in the question, runTest :s It just go through after and before methods, I guess it's because they come from Cucumber framework.

Comment: maybe - did a test without cucumber? is it working than or still problems? did you add this to the before method?  @Before
  public void before() {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
  }